# import CallKit crashes randomly on iOS 9

Tags: crash, ios9, xcode8, callkit

I have imported CallKit framework as optional only. But **import CallKit** crashes while running on iOS 9 at launch. But works perfectly on iOS 10.
It worked fine in XCode 8 beta 6 but this issue is happening only on XCode 8.
The code is in Swift 3.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If you have not done so already, please [file a Radar](http://bugreport.apple.com) with Apple about this, including the crash report file generated and all relevant details about the Xcode and SDK version you are running on, and ideally a small Xcode project which demonstrates the issue

Answer (score 1):

CallKit API is only for iOS 10.0+. It won't work for iOS 9.0. Use a condition for iOS version 9.0 and 10.0 to avoid the crash.

Reference : https://developer.apple.com/reference/callkit?language=objc

Answer (score 1):

There is/was a bug in Swift 3 language that wrongly links module libraries [github pull request](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/5055), that is fixed now, but the fix is not yet implemented in XCode, not even in beta.

You could get latest swift toolchain build from [link](https://swift.org/download/#releases) and install it to XCode to try and see the fix, but the app would not be approved for Appstore as it's stated here

[image: apple approval swift version]

You got two solutions;

- wait for apple to release XCode with new version of swift 3.0.2+
- or revert your code back to swift 2, where it works, with "Use Legacy Swift Language Version" flag in Build Settings [image: Build Settings -> Use Legacy Swift Language Version]

If you choose to revert back to swift 2, brace yourself with a lot of patience :D

Comment: Thanks. I'll wait for the new XCode version.